# SQL find & replace with variables

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I am trying to clean up too long meta description which are over 165 chars. I have this query:

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang
SET meta_description = REPLACE(meta_description, 'Depth 12 mm', '')
```

The only trouble is that there are various depth available and instead of replacing them oine by one, is there a way to do it for all of them? Something like

```
UPDATE ps_product_lang
SET meta_description = REPLACE(meta_description, 'Depth * mm', '') * WHERE = any value
```

Comment: sorry for not including it. mysql.

Comment: search for "regexp replace mysql" on this site...

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have an easy solution for this because REPLACE() does not have any support for patterns, wildcards or regular expressions.

I would suggest using something like this:

```
/* EXTENDED Functionality allows user to use patterns up to 100 characters long, not just 1 character
/* Original @  http://www.nacodes.com/#ECHo75Y7RYXbgow0.99 */ 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION  `regex_replace`(pattern VARCHAR(100),replacement VARCHAR(1000),original VARCHAR(1000))

RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE temp VARCHAR(1000);
 DECLARE ch VARCHAR(100);
 DECLARE i INT;
 DECLARE j INT;
 DECLARE qbTemp VARCHAR(1000);

 SET i = 1;
 SET j = 1;
 SET temp = '';
 SET qbTemp = '';

 IF original REGEXP pattern THEN
  loop_label: LOOP
   IF i>CHAR_LENGTH(original) THEN
    LEAVE loop_label; 
   END IF;
   SET ch = SUBSTRING(original,i,CHAR_LENGTH(pattern));
   IF NOT ch REGEXP pattern THEN
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,LEFT(ch,1));
    SET i=i+1;
   ELSE
    SET temp = CONCAT(temp,replacement);
    SET i=i+CHAR_LENGTH(pattern);
   END IF;
  END LOOP;
 ELSE
  SET temp = original;
 END IF;
 SET temp = TRIM(BOTH replacement FROM temp);
 SET temp = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(temp , CONCAT(replacement,replacement),CONCAT(replacement,'#')),CONCAT('#',replacement),''),'#','');
 RETURN temp;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[Source here](https://gist.github.com/daxmaximum/8551033)

As an alternative, you can always export the data to a file, alter the fields in a text editor or sed, for instance, and import it back to MySQL.